# SELECT LAST ROW WITH AN INNER JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, select, join

I have two relational tables [category] and [briefs].
I want to select the last ROW FROM briefs WHERE briefs.category_id = category.category_id;

```
[Category]
category_id
category_name

[briefs]
brief_id
category_id
brief_file_num
brief_date



 "SELECT brief_file_num,category_id FROM briefs,category 
WHERE briefs.category_id = category.category_id ORDER BY briefs.brief_file_num 
DESC LIMIT 1";
```

I am receiving the following error: `"Column 'category_id' in field list is ambiguous"`

Comment: qualify the select statement select list with table name..like if x is column in  table1 you have to put table1.x in your select clause query

Comment: mind losing the CAPS in the title?? this is called "Shouting" and nobody likes getting shouted at, do you? I didn't think so.

Comment: always try to use the format: `table_name`.`column_name` as `alias`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should explicitally add the tables names  for avoid ambiguity

```
   "SELECT briefs.brief_file_num, briefs.category_id 
     FROM briefs,category 
     WHERE briefs.category_id = category.category_id ORDER BY briefs.brief_file_num 
    DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 1):

Even when both category have the same value. you need to specify what table are you refering too because both have a column with that name

Also use explict `JOIN` sintaxis, Aaron Bertrand wrote a nice article [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) about it.

```
 SELECT briefs.brief_file_num,
        briefs.category_id    
 FROM briefs
 INNER JOIN category 
    ON briefs.category_id = category.category_id 
 ORDER BY briefs.brief_file_num 
 DESC LIMIT 1"
```

Answer (score 0):

Both tables have a `category_id`, which is ambiguous. Use `category.category_id` instead!

```
SELECT brief_file_num,category.category_id FROM briefs,category 
WHERE briefs.category_id = category.category_id ORDER BY briefs.brief_file_num 
DESC LIMIT 1
```